# Ubuntu 14.04: After upgrade to kernel 4.4.0-116-generic Broadcom wlan does not function

Tags: 14.04, wireless, kernel, broadcom

After auto-update from kernel 4.4.0-112-generic to 4.4.0.116-generic, the Broadcom wlan adapter is no longer available. As I did not yet have time for further research, I removed the 4.4.0-116 kernel package and switched back to 4.4.0-112 to keep the laptop functional.

With kernel 4.4.0-112, it appears that the wlan-adapter uses the module wl.

I can't find any info on this issue in the 4.4.0-116 package's release notes.

Do I need to update the wl-module manually? Do I need another module?

Any help appreciated! And happy to provide more info if anyone point me to the right places to find it.

Comment: I had the same problem with my linux mint laptop today after upgrading from 4.4.0-112. I was unable to find any other solution so i just rolled back to my previous kernel.

Comment: In the 4.4.0-116 kernel, try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`  There is an issue with gcc and compiling right now https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1750937

Comment: @Jeremy31 I tried that, but it didnt work. It just disabled my wifi even when i boot with the  4.4.0-112 kernel. In case you have the same problem I fixed it by just switching a driver my driver with an other + reboot and then switch back to my original driver + reboot from the driver manager. I hope they fix it or else I will stay with the  4.4.0-112 kernel forever.

Comment: @theVoid you may also need the gcc-5 update otherwise the vermagic for the wl module isn't correct for the 4.4.0-116 kernel

Comment: @Jeremy31 yup that did fix the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, resolved by updating to the latest version of [bcmwl-kernel-source](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/bcmwl-kernel-source)